Azure Document Intelligence - Base64 Degredation
In Azure Document Intelligence studio When I run tests on a pdf I'm getting expected results.

Based on the same exact document hitting the analyze service with a base64 source I get back different results.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get the same results as the test model in Document Intelligence Studio as hitting the actual analyze service. Does having a base64 source drastically change the analyze result?
Service request with body:
await fetch(analyzeUri, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: { "base64Source":"..." },
  })

